# Requesting MS Graph Access Token to implement Subscription User change in AAD

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to implement msgraph subscription using java. I have the following code. I am able to fetch access token , but not able to use graphClient and also has doubts about how to give notificationUrl and its backend handling.

try{

```
           final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                   .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                   .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                   .tenantId(TENANT)
                   .build();

           final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
                   GraphServiceClient
                           .builder()
                           .authenticationProvider( Some authprovider here goes here )
                           .buildClient();

           Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
           subscription.changeType = "created";
           subscription.notificationUrl = "http://localhost:4200/1/mynotification";
           subscription.resource = "/users";
           subscription.expirationDateTime = OffsetDateTimeSerializer.deserialize("2022-03-20T18:23:45.9356913Z");
           subscription.clientState = "secretClientValue";
           //   subscription.latestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2";

           Subscription graphresult = graphClient.subscriptions()
                   .buildRequest()
                   .post(subscription);
       
           System.out.println("graphresult :"+graphresult );
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           logger.info("\nException : "+e);
       }
```

I hope someone can help me! It will be a great help !

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: hi @juunas I am getting following EXCEPTION java.lang.ClassCastException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication cannot be cast to com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential

Comment: Right, a ConfidentialClientApplication cannot be cast to a token credential. I think you need to construct a ClientSecretCredential instead of the ConfidentialClientApplication. At least that's what it's called in the .NET SDK.

Comment: hi @juunas I am not getting it right even after using ClientSecretCredential , What should be used with ConfidentialClientApplication  instead of token credential ?

Comment: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error executing the request
This is the error that I am receiving

Comment: Okay, that's not quite enough info what could be wrong.. Is there anything more on the exception?

Comment: 18:42:48.026 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR c.a.identity.ClientSecretCredential - Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]
: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error executing the request
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:411)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:226)